deploy extra artifacts but not the jar
Using Maven, I am able to generate 2 extra artifacts (some metadata for this version) during the build, and deploy them in our Nexus instance, using build-helper-maven-plugin plugin.
While doing that, the jar is automatically deployed too, which is a normal default behavior. But I don't really need to deploy it, because after I am building a Docker image with the jar in it right after : storing the jar in Nexus is useless, we're not going to use it as a dependency in another project.
All I need to publish in Nexus for a given version is really the 2 extra metadata artifacts I am generating.
Is there a way to configure either install or deploy plugins to filter out the jar from what is being deployed ? both have a skip option, but it's all or nothing : I could not find a way to apply a filter on the resources.

Change the type to pom and it'll only publish the POM? Unless this is preventing to use the plugin that generated your other artifacts.

Chaging the packaging to pom is fine but check to which life cycle phase the build-helper-maven-plugin is bound to... the issue might be the generated jar file... do you use that as source to generate your metadata from it?

build-helper-maven-plugin is bound to package phase. I still need compile the jar because I need it to generate the metadata (using exec-maven-plugin plugin) and I need it for my docker image right after.

I don't think so, and I would not do it even if I could.
Having side artifacts (like your metadata artifacts) without the main artifact is not how Maven storage is designed.
On the other hand, it probably does not really hurt to have the JAR, even if it wastes a little bit of space on the hard disk.
